# Why is my Temperature gauge keeps going up to hot and car loses power whenever this happens

Tags: electrical

The problem started a year ago. I changed the engine because there was oil coming out of somewhere. The mechanic said I had a hairline crack. I changed all of the sensors etc ... not too car savvy ... Carried it for an electrical check ... yet the problem remains. I also have the problem of putting in steering wheel fluid very so often.

Comment: It looks as though you have two questions (problems) here. First you may want to split out the temp gauge from the power steering problem. Then, you'll want to add a bunch more information to the questions, such as what kind make/year/model/engine of your car (add to both questions). Also, what did the mechanic say to you when you took it in? Did the temp gauge work correctly before you had the engine replaced? How exactly does the temp gauge behave, such as, does it just jump up to the high mark and peg, or does it slowly rise? Give us some more information and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with an '89 Honda overheating and coolant coming out of the overflow tube on the highway.  It was preceded by some erratic idling around town.

It turned out that the thermostat had gone bad and coolant was no longer circulating properly and thus causing the engine to overheat.  The engine coolant temperature sensor is on the engine side of the thermostat and, as the coolant was not at the proper level, it was getting hot steam over the sensor rather than what I assume would have been cooler coolant.

The ECT sensor on my car affects starting dramatically if it's disconnected, as it once was due to an open circuit between it and the car's computer.

Bottom line: that sensor on my car affects engine performance by creating hard starting and racing and erratic idling, for example.

You can check a thermostat by boiling it in water.  It should open up when hot.  Fun to do if you're curious but they only cost about $7 IIRC so just get a new one.  Make sure you get the right one for your car as they come with different temperature settings.

PS -- on my car it's not enough to just add coolant (when it's a cold engine, of course!).  There's an air pocket around the thermostat and there's a bleed screw there to bleed off trapped air and allow the sensor to be fully immersed.

So, check connections to sensor, coolant level, and thermostat.  You changed your sensors so you can eliminate that, assuming that one wasn't missed.